# Shadow artifacts during animation in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

Here are css, html and js to reproduce:

html:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div>123</div>
    <div id="inner">345</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#outer {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#inner {
    height: 200px;
}
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    $('#outer').click(function() {
        $('#inner').slideUp();
    });
});
```

and http://jsfiddle.net/DwApF/ as well

Any workarounds for this issue?

[image]

Comment: +1 - That is a nasty behavior indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Attempt #1**

http://jsfiddle.net/DwApF/3/

This hides the shadow and then restores it after the slide is complete. It's a hack of a solution but this is a manner in which a variety of behaviors can be circumvented.

**Attempt #2**

http://jsfiddle.net/DwApF/11/

This does a simultaneous animation of both outer and inner containers. It slides the drop shadow with no artifacts. However, you will need to manually manipulate the height of the outer container, and also deal with hiding the contents of the inner container. It **does** eliminate the artifact issue though.

**Attempt #3 - My Preferred Solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/DwApF/12/

This still uses a simultaneous animation of both outer/inner containers. I see no artifacts in IE9. It also handles hiding the inner container's content using `overflow: hidden`.

The sizing of the outer container still must be done manually, but I think this is an adequate solution. There should be a way to determine the collapsed height using jQuery so that this value doesn't need to be hard-coded.

This solution works in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox. Note that I have added some colors/borders so that it's easier to see the different containers.

Comment: I don't think there is. Looks like an IE9 bug, [also mentioned here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180922/parent-div-drop-shadow-bug-when-children-is-animated-with-jquery-in-internet-exp)

Comment: @JoshSmith - thanks for linking that question; I posted solution #3 as an answer.

Comment: @zerkms - I think simultaneous animation (solution #3) may be a viable solution.

Comment: Well, unfortunately `overflow: hidden;` trick doesn't work with my development code (which is slightly more complex than the example) but it is the challenged I should solve myself. Thank you :-)

Comment: I had exactly the same problem ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180922 ). This is definitely a bug, then? Great answer anyway; thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The bad news is that the bug is worse in IE10. The good news is that this simple rule seems to fix it - at least it does in IE10. Since IE9 supports the :after pseudo class, it should also work.

```
.Element:after {
content: ".";
font-size: 1px;
display: inline;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Replace .Element with either the class name or ID (#Element) of the object that shows the artifact.

In IE9, often assigning overflow: hidden will work - though that does not work in IE10.

Comment: Could you take the initial jsfiddle and modify it accordingly?

Comment: Works great, works better with line-height: 0, and content: " "

Comment: beautifull this was exactly the solution I needed. just needed to change `content: " "; height: 0;`

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me - just animate the box-shadow attribute of the parent at the same time:

```
$(function() {
    $('#outer').click(function() {
        $('#inner').slideUp();
        $(this).animate({'box-shadow': '0px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work me: Simply wrap the div in *another* div with these styles on the outer div

```
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 0px;
overflow: visible
```

No idea why this did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to put the DIV I wanted to vanish inside **another** DIV as was mentioned earlier.... HOWEVER.....  I don't apply any special styles to it.  Instead, all I did was use jQuery to target the new parent DIV and make that disappear instead.

It got rid of those annoying shadow artifacts for me.  (on IE10)